# Get child ul's to fill 100% width of parent div evenly?

Tags: html, css

I have a series of ul's in a footer that I want to evenly fill the entire width of a containing div.

There are six ul's, so I've tried using a width property of 16.66666666666667% for each to add up to 100%, the width of the container, but this is wrapping the final ul below.

I obviously can't just use a lower number as this won't properly fill to a total width of 100%.

Any ideas?

```css
    footer > row
    {
        height: 50px;
        display: block;
        padding: 30px 10%;
    }

    footer > #footerNav > ul
    {
        display: inline-block;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 16%;
    }
```

```html
    <footer>
            
            <row id="footerNav">
                
                <ul>
                    
                    <li>Address</li>
                    
                    <li>Line 1,</li>
                    
                    <li>Line 2,</li>
                    
                    <li>London</li>
                    
                    <li>Postcode</li>
                    
                </ul>
                
                <ul>
                    
                    <li>Contact</li>
                    
                    <li>T: +44 (0) 0000 000000</li>
                    
                    <li>Email: info@companyname.com</li>
                    
                </ul>
                
                <ul>
                    
                    <li>Links</a></li>
                    
                    <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                    
                    <li><a href="#">Range</a></li>
                    
                    <li><a href="#">Brands</a></li>
                    
                    <li><a href="#">Case Studies</a></li>
                    
                </ul>
                
                <ul>
                    
                    <li>Media</li>
                    
                    <li><a href="#">Brochure Download</a></li>
                    
                    <li><a href="#">Watch our Videos</a></li>
                    
                </ul>
                
                <ul>
                    
                    <li>Legal</li>
                    
                    <li><a href="#">Legal Notice</a></li>
                    
                    <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                    
                </ul>
                
                <ul>
                    
                    <li>Translator</li>
                    
                    <li>
                        
                        <select name="Select Language">
                            
                            <option value="Select Language">Select Language</option>
                            
                            <option value="English (United Kingdom)">English (United Kingdom)</option>
                            
                            <option value="English (United States)">English (United States)</option>
                            
                            <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
                        
                        </select>
                        
                    </li>
                    
                </ul>
                
            </row>
            
            <row>
                
                <a>© Copyright ******</a>
                
            </row>
            
        </footer>
```

Comment: Maybe you should use bootstrap's grid system. I think it's what you need. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display: flex;` on the parent `#footerNav` and `flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: 0;` on the `ul`'s for them to evenly distribute the available width in `#footerNav`

```css
footer > row {
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  padding: 30px 10%;
}

#footerNav {
  display: flex;
}

footer > #footerNav > ul {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 16%;
}
```

```html
<footer>

  <row id="footerNav">

    <ul>

      <li>Address</li>

      <li>Line 1,</li>

      <li>Line 2,</li>

      <li>London</li>

      <li>Postcode</li>

    </ul>

    <ul>

      <li>Contact</li>

      <li>T: +44 (0) 0000 000000</li>

      <li>Email: info@companyname.com</li>

    </ul>

    <ul>

      <li>Links</a>
      </li>

      <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>

      <li><a href="#">Range</a></li>

      <li><a href="#">Brands</a></li>

      <li><a href="#">Case Studies</a></li>

    </ul>

    <ul>

      <li>Media</li>

      <li><a href="#">Brochure Download</a></li>

      <li><a href="#">Watch our Videos</a></li>

    </ul>

    <ul>

      <li>Legal</li>

      <li><a href="#">Legal Notice</a></li>

      <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>

    </ul>

    <ul>

      <li>Translator</li>

      <li>

        <select name="Select Language">

                        <option value="Select Language">Select Language</option>

                        <option value="English (United Kingdom)">English (United Kingdom)</option>

                        <option value="English (United States)">English (United States)</option>

                        <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>

                    </select>

      </li>

    </ul>

  </row>

  <row>

    <a>© Copyright ******</a>

  </row>

</footer>
```

Comment: YES! Did look at flexbox for a solution but everywhere that described it made it much more confusing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the 10% left and right padding on the row element.